# Cakephp + Jquery : how to user jquery methods?

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp

My problem is really simple.

I've a lot of links like :

```
$this->Html->link(__('Calculer'), 'log_import/'.$suivi['Suivi']['date'], array('class' => 'logImport')
```

As you can see, the href attribute of my 'a' tag changes on every links (kind of dates like '2012-01-01', '2012-10-15', etc...)

When i click on my link, jquery code is executing :

```
$this->Js
    ->get('.logImport')
    ->event('click',
        $this->Js->request(
          array('action' => '$(this).attr("href")'),
          array('async' => true,
                'update' => '#test')
          ));
```

And i get an error because the URL used by the ajax request is :

```
/suivis/$(this).attr(&quot;href&quot;)
```

and not :

```
/suivis/log_import/2012-01-01
```

Comment: How come you are not using the JsHelpers Link method? [Link] (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html#JsHelper::link)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will work :

```
array('action' => '$(this).attr("href")')
```

It seems the value is treated as a string.

My suggestion is to use raw jquery code:

```
$('.logImport',this.DOMDoc).each(
  function(index, object){

    var href = $(this).get(0).href;
    $(this).get(0).href = "javascript:void(0);"

    // attach click function for each link
    $(this).click(function() {

        // make request here            
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: href,
            ...
        })

    });
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, finally i used "pure" jquery code in the JS Helper buffer.

This is my code (you can directly use $(this).attr and bypass the each loop ;-)

```
$this->Js->buffer('
  $(".logImport").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr("href"),
        })
        .done(function(){
          alert("OK");
          })
        .fail(function(){
          alert("FAILED");
          });

    });
');
```

By the way, i'm still interested in the answer if anybody knows....

Comment: By "pure" I meant not mixing PHP with Javascript. The Js helper may be useful in some cases, but if you use it just to display a script, then it becomes unnecessary. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9495651/why-use-cakephps-jshelper